# What primary sources are there for Charles I's seizure of gold from the Tower mint?

Tags: england, english-civil-war

What primary sources are there for Charles the First's 1640 seizure of gold from the Tower mint?

*[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_I_of_England#Finances)* is a tertiary source.

Comment: For a primary source, you might want to try the UK National Archives which contains the record books of the [Royal Mint](http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/browse/r/h/C1212).

Answer (score 5):

You might consult

- Challis, C. E., ed. 1992. A New History of the Royal Mint.; or,
- Craig, J. 1953. The Mint: A History of the London Mint from A.D. 287 to 1948.

The Quarterly Journal of Economics (available from the unciteable Google Books) cites the following primary sources:

1. Burnet's [History of my own time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert_Burnet#History_of_My_Own_Time) and
2. [Rushworth's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Rushworth) *Historical Collections*
3. and [Annals of the Coinage](https://archive.org/details/annalsofcoinageo01rudiuoft) by Ruding, Rogers